# Can't login to YouTube since changing account name

Tags: youtube, google-plus, google-account

For a while I got periodic messages on YouTube telling me to move my account to Google Plus and to change the name. Ever since I made that change I can no longer login to YouTube. I get the following error message: [image: error screen]

Which says "You are not eligible to create an account" and "Sorry, your login was incorrect".

This situation is very frustrating. I wish I never decided to change my YouTube account name! Does anyone here know how to fix this situation so that I can login to YouTube normally (like I could before the account name change).

Answer (score 1):

My first suggestion is to go to the google login page like https://www.google.com/accounts/ and log in, and then go to http://www.youtube.com .  Since you linked your account it should automatically showed you as logged in.

Comment: Also, please tell me what happens with these steps:
1) Can you login to https://www.google.com/accounts/
2) Are you using a username or email to login to youtube.com

Answer (score 0):

Here is a good place to find advice about your problem on Google+:

**[Google+ Helper Community](https://plus.google.com/communities/105619967999215909743)**

I searched for YouTube in the community and found at least one post that may help you:
https://plus.google.com/103172072345300450419/posts/AK6J3eQJn4z

I hope this helps!

Cheers, Jaana